# Python: How to pretty print the cards

Tags: python, poker

I just started learning python and then this card game came out and I had no idea what to do. Basically, I need to create a for-loop inside of which I ask the user for card:. Most importantly, I need to define a function outside of main(), like def ppcard( card ):, and prints out the "pretty-print" version of that card. If a user put card: 4h, the output should be 4 of Spade. So that's where I got confused and I tried lots of times but I don't know how I can do the pretty print. I don't know how to match the values in deck like the 's' in '2s' to 'Spade'.

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking; "So that's where I got confused and I tried lots of times but I don't know how I can do the pretty print. I don't know how to match the values in deck like the 's' in '2s' to 'Spade'.". What is the question ; pretty printing or matching strings?

Comment: pretty printing. like how can I print '2 of Spade' from '2s'

Answer (score 2):

You can use the respective letter in `card` as keys for the `ranks` and `suits` dicts:

```
def ppcard(card):
    print(ranks[card[0]], 'of', suits[card[1]])
```

Also note that you're missing quotes around the strings for the keys of the `suits` dict:

```
suits = {"s": "Spades", "h": "Hearts", "d": "Diamonds", "c": "Clubs"}
```

Comment: Also, you have to correct the rank dictionary (to use quotes around the strings)

Comment: Thanks!!! But there is an error: ppcard() missing 1 required positional argument: 'card' Do i need to do anything with the position of main() and ppcard()?

Comment: Yes you would have to call `ppcard` with argument, such as `ppcard('2s')`.